# Python: Can't Convert lists from SQL

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to learn Python, and right now I want to import some data from SQL. Unfortunately I have a problem that I wasn't capable of solving. I am getting the following error message:

> cursor.execute("select * from matchinfo WHERE matchid = '%i'" %
>   Matchid) TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not pyodbc.Row"

I guess the issue is that the list data isn't formatted as integers, however when I try to do stuff like "Matchid[0] = int(Matchid[0])" (and then print out Matchid[0]) it's not working either. So I am not really sure how to fix the problem. The code is below and thanks in advance.

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-    
FCDHA0J\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Data')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select matchid from matchinfo where matchid > 1 order by dato asc")

Matchinfo = cursor.fetchall()


for Matchid in Matchinfo:

    print(Matchinfo[0])

    cursor.execute("select * from matchinfo WHERE matchid = '%i'" % Matchid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast `Pyodbc.Row` into a `integer`. To fix this just make this changes:

```
cursor.execute("select * from matchinfo WHERE matchid = %s", (Matchid[0],))
```

Why you need `fetchall`, you need to work offline or something?

Just do this:

```
cursor.execute("select matchid from matchinfo where matchid > 1 order by dato asc")

for Matchid in Matchinfo:
    match_id = Matchid[0]
    cursor.execute("select * from matchinfo WHERE matchid = '%i'" % match_id)
```

And you are gain some performance if the table is large, because you are retreiving one result at a time. In the other way, you are fetching all the results into memory at once.